# How do you turn off Aero Glass on an underpriveleged account?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, themes, aero, privileges

The computers at my university all have the Aero Glass theme enabled which makes many things unresponsive. The student accounts here have reduced privileges (no control panel, no accessibility options).

Is there any way to change to a less resource-intensive theme without permissions?

Comment: When you right-click on the desktop, do you see a "Personalize" option?

Comment: Yes, but clicking on it says "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator."

Comment: You could contact your system administrator and tell them that the computers feel sluggish with aero turned on.